# Find conditional distribuition of iid random variables

Tags: probability

$X_1, X_2, X_3$ iid with geo(p) distribution
Find the distribution of $X_1|X_1+X_2$.

$$P(X_1=k|X_1+X_2=n)=...=\frac{p^2(1-p)^n}{P(X_1+X_2=n)}
$$

It's independent from k, so it will be uniformly distributed.
The answer is $U(\{0,1,2,...,X_1+X_2\})$ - what I don't understand is why the last value is $X_1+X_2$.

Comment: If you prefer you called it $n$... as it is an uniform variable you need to state a support.

Comment: I don't know how to find this support here. I mean, it seems strange to me that the biggest value for $X_1$ is $X_1+X_2$. Is it possible to find it somehow more formally than just see it, because I can't see it?

Comment: But you used $X_1+X_2=n$ in your formulas. As $X_2$ cannot be negative, it is clear that the maximum value for $X_1$, under the $X_1+X_2=n$ constraint, is $n$

Comment: Okay, thanks, it makes sense.